# Segment matrix of points based on coordinate values in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a (n, 2) matrix of 2-D coordinates. What is the most efficient way to segment or split the matrix into different parts depending on the x or y coordinates?  I am just looking for rectangular regions, so something that would accomplish the following, for example:

```
split_on_y_value(PointMatrix, yvalue) -> returns Matrix1 = [all points with y<yvalue] and Matrix2 = [all points with y>=yvalue]
```

or

```
get_points_in_range(PointMatrix, y1, y2) -> returns 1 matrix will all points with y value in between y1 and y2
```

I know this is related to image segmentation, but this is a far simpler problem, I just don't know the right Matlab/Octave notation or package is to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty straightforward. Here it is for the `y < yvalue` case:

```
A=randi(10,10,2)
yvalue=7;

B=A(A(:,2)<yvalue,:)
```

Output is:

```
A =

   7   7
   7   9
   2   1
   7   9
   7   1
   3   7
   9   6
   3   9
   9   4
   6   4

B =

   2   1
   7   1
   9   6
   9   4
   6   4
```

The remainder of the problem is left as an exercise for the reader, as they say.